# Sample 2000 elements randomly from tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Suppose you have a dataset containing 50,000 examples and want to sample uniformly 2000 elements.

For example:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path_filename_records)
dataset = (dataset
           .map(parse_record, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
           .batch(bs)
           .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
          )
```

How do you do this with tf.data?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets)?

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that only works with two or more datasets. I need to add a working example...